# MySQL : Group By Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am taking a coursera online course on MySQL. In one of the exercises, I have to

"Write a query that outputs the total number of unique User_Guids in each combination of State and ZIP code (postal code) in the United States, sorted first by state name in ascending alphabetical order, and second by total number of unique User_Guids in descending order"

So I wrote a code like this:

```
SELECT state, zip, COUNT(DISTINCT user_guid) AS NUM_Users
FROM users
WHERE Country="US"
GROUP BY zip
ORDER BY State ASC, NUM_Users DESC;
```

and got **5027 rows** in my answer.

The correct code is the same with one notable exception:

```
GROUP BY State, zip
```

which gets 5043 rows.

I'm confused. Why doesnt my code work and give the right answer?

Thanks !

Comment: group by state. You select state but group by State

Comment: because there are zip codes which are available in more than one states?

Comment: That first GROUP BY is invalid, will return an unpredictable result in older MySQL versions, will raise an error in new versions (unless in compatibility mode.) The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jens mentioned, turns out that there are multiple entries with a state but NULL ZIP code. When I don't group by state, all those NULL ZIP codes get rolled into one.

Grouping by state and ZIP allows those NULL ZIP codes to remain in the output, under their respective states.